# Ionic3 on button click iframe.contentWindow.postMessage, Need to stop refreshing the url/iframe on each click

Tags: typescript, iframe, ionic3, postmessage

**I'm using iframe in ionic 3 to pass data between parent and child.**

on clicking on the button I'm able to pass the data using **iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('value', '*')**

but on every time on button click, iframe getting refreshed.

I do the following:

Ionic 3 html code
*/home.html*

```
<button ion-button id="message_button" (click)="sendMessage()">My iframe</button>

<iframe id="the_iframe" #iframe height="100%" width="100%" [src]="urlpaste()" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

Ionic 3 typescript code
*/home.ts*

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;
  myIframe:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  urlpaste(){
    this.url = "http://localhost:5000/iframe.html";
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myIframe = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow
  }

  sendMessage() {
    var random = Math.random();
    this.myIframe.postMessage(random, '*');
  }

}
```

Plain HTML code
*/iframe.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>iframe Window</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #D53C2F;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Hello there, i'm an iframe</h1>
    <p>Send Message: <button id="message_button">Hi parent</button></p>
    <p>Got Message:</p>
    <div id="results"></div>

    <script>
        // addEventListener support for IE8
        function bindEvent(element, eventName, eventHandler) {
            if (element.addEventListener) {
                element.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);
            } else if (element.attachEvent) {
                element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, eventHandler);
            }
        }

        // Send a message to the parent
        var sendMessage = function (msg) {
            // Make sure you are sending a string, and to stringify JSON
            window.parent.postMessage(msg, '*');
        };

        var results = document.getElementById('results'),
            messageButton = document.getElementById('message_button');

        // Listen to messages from parent window
        bindEvent(window, 'message', function (e) {
            results.innerHTML = e.data;
        });

        // Send random message data on every button click
        bindEvent(messageButton, 'click', function (e) {
            var random = Math.random();
            sendMessage('' + random);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it little bit late. But it will definitely help someone in future.

HTML

```
<iframe id="the_iframe" #iframe height="100%" width="100%" [src]="url" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

TS

```
    url = "";
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
     this.url = this.urlpaste();
    }

  urlpaste(){
    let url = "http://localhost:5000/iframe.html";
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
```

You have to use "url" variable in iframe src. Don't function directly there...